# Freshbook style email template using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, email

Freshbooks allows users to create custom email template body with exposed variables.

But while sending email Freshbooks appends standard logo header & footer info to each email template.

This means Freshbooks is saving user generated email template in DB & at run-time it is appending header+body+footer & passes the string to template generator to create final email body.

How can I do so using Nodejs?
1) What template engine or package can I use to make this happen
2) Nodejs templates all loads from a file saved on HDD. Should I also save user generated custom body in file as partial template?
3) Would also like to have template package which can allow to change delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused in regards to nodejs. It's true that most express view engines need the views to be stored on the file system. However, nothing is inherently stopping you from writing raw html directly to the response or creating raw html emails with Nodemailer. For your use case you can use [handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) or another templating engine directly to generate your emails from any text.

Comment: Yes Sir I managed to make use of handlebar for the purpose. Apparently my concerned was in regards to structuring of this service. ie How do these companies implement such a module. Of course I couldn't find much in reference to this for Nodejs. Anyways sincere thanks